# The application has stopped unexpectedly try again in samsung galaxy ace

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I made an application with android sdk 4.4.2 and works perfectly on the emulator nexus eclipse.

The problem is that when you install it on a samsung galaxy ace GT-S5830M , android 2.3.6 , me the message:

The application has stopped unexpectedly try again

What will be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that there's no logcat here for us to debug from.  Fix that and maybe you can get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile it in API 9 or lower. You can't run Android 4.4.2 applications on a Android 2.3.6 device. To do this you first need to install the right API.

If you don't have this then just go to the SDK Manager (the fifth icon on the left of your Quick Access bar) then mark the right api and install it. After your done, restart eclipse. Then right-click on your project > properties > Android and mark the right API you want to use, in this case API 9 and compile it. This should fix the problem.

If this doesn't work you can also just change the API version in the manifest file. Just change it to the version you want to use.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="number-of-version-you-want" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change mininum requiement version SDK from Manifest.xml, sdk 4.4 is okay for all older versions.

Also make correct yourself all methods, which are still definied into API 12(Android 2.3.6).